# Sinatra: Shotgun/Rerun having trouble starting sometimes?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm not sure if it's something I added in my code recently, but when I try and use Shotgun or Rerun to run my server, it will sometimes hang before it actually says the "Listening on 0.0.0.0" line in Terminal.

I haven't seen this occur when I run my Sinatra server directly with ruby.

There's no errors popping up anywhere - it just seems to hang on starting or reloading after a save... happens about 20% of the time I'd say.

How can I figure out what is causing the issue? I would assume it's either A) something in my code, or B) something going on with my file system.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) with [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun)? shotgun auto reloads the connection on change.

If you're serving it with [puma](http://puma.io) or something that doesn't refresh when you change the project, then rerun would be necessary.

If you're concerned with speed have a look at this: http://scorchedrb.com/docs/further_reading/code_reloading

Comment: No no - Shotgun *or* Rerun. I'll check out the code reloading page, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Wrong answer then.
Keep in mind that `rerun` doesn't actually serve code, it just dose something when the files change